# How do I prevent 2 of my radio buttons from lighting up at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make my own little rock paper scissors program using Tkinter because I'm bored. I'm using radio buttons to specify the player's action. But, for some reason, upon running the program, 2 of the 3 radio buttons light up. Occasionally 3 of the 3. I don't believe it should be doing this.

Here is my code if necessary:

```
from tkinter import *
app=Tk()

playersel=0
RBttn = Radiobutton(text = "Rock", variable = playersel,value = 'Rock')
RBttn2 = Radiobutton(text = "Paper", variable = playersel, value = 'Paper')
RBttn3=Radiobutton(text='Scissors',variable=playersel,value='Scissors')

RBttn.place(x=10,y=10)
RBttn2.place(x=10,y=30)
RBttn3.place(x=10,y=50)

app.mainloop()
```

I'm using python 3.10.4 if that matters.

Comment: `playersel` need to be an instance of `StringVar()` with an initial value not equal to the three values for the three radiobuttons and cannot be empty string as well.  For example, `playersel = StringVar(value='none')`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I prevent 2 of my radio buttons from lighting up at the same
> time

- Added `IntVar()` for all 3 raidobuttons.
- Added parameter `variable=var` for all 3 raidobuttons.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

var = IntVar()
playersel = 0

RBttn = Radiobutton(app, text="Rock", variable=var, value = 'Rock')
RBttn2 = Radiobutton(app, text="Paper", variable=var, value = 'Paper')
RBttn3 = Radiobutton(app, text='Scissors',variable=var, value='Scissors')

RBttn.place(x=10,y=10)
RBttn2.place(x=10,y=30)
RBttn3.place(x=10,y=50)

app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot before and after:

[image]    [image]